# Copying cell range to a different workbook

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I've got the below code to copy a range of different cells to the next available row in another workbook. The issue is that it's pasting the formula's not the values.

```
Sub SaveInlife()
    Dim wb As Workbook, NR As Long
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\caseys\Downloads\Operations Score Card.xlsx")
    NR = Sheets("IN LIFE").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REPORT")
    .Range("AB85").Copy Destination:=wb.Sheets("IN LIFE").Range("A" & NR)
    End With

    wb.Close savechanges:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out

Replaced

```
.Range("AB85").Copy Destination:=wb.Sheets("IN LIFE").Range("A" & NR)
```

With

```
wb.Sheets("IN LIFE").Range("A" & NR).Value = .Range("AB85").Value
```

Seems to do what I need it to :)

Answer (score 0):

not sure how to do it in one line of code but

```
.Range("AB85").Copy 
wb.Sheets("IN LIFE").Range("A" & NR).PasteSpecial xlValues
```